# Rounding-off from whole numbers to whole numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math

So I have some numbers `x = 320232` `y = 2301` `z = 12020305`. I want to round these numbers off using JavaScript so that they become `x = 320000` `y = 2300` `z = 12000000`.

I tried `Math.round` and `Math.floor` but turns out that they only work with decimal values like
`a = 3.1; Math.round(a); // Outputs 3` and not whole numbers.

So my question is can we round of whole numbers using JavaScript and If yes then how?

Edit: I want it to the round of to the starting 3 digit places as seen in the variables above. Like If there was another variable called `c = 423841` It should round off to become `c = 424000`.

Comment: Why is x not 300000? Why is 2301, not 2300. Is there a uniformity in the logic?

Comment: @TusharShahi Yes there is, I want to round of to the first 3 digits. Like x to be 320000 and y to be 2000.

Comment: @TusharShahi Just like how z rounds of to 12000000, just to the first 3 digits.

Comment: @TusharShahi Imagine another variable called `b`, `b = 321523` If we round off it should become `b = 321000`

Comment: @TusharShahi I did some edits to the question please check now.

Comment: @Stranger - So not rounding, truncating (`321523` would round to `322000`). Or is it rounding, but ignoring all but the first three digits? What do you want for `325100`? `325000` or `326000`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Kind of not, for `325100` I would want `325000` but If It was `325900` I would want `326000`

Comment: If x = 300 what would be the result?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, my bad for that, but yes I would want 424000 for that. Let me update my question.

Comment: @Usiel It would be 300.

Comment: If you search for "round to nearest multiple" you'll find a plethora of duplicate stackoverflow questions. But you need to first determine which power of 10 you want to round to a multiple of, by counting the number of digits of your number (for instance by taking its logarithm).

Comment: So If the number is less than 1000 it shouldn't be rounded?

Comment: @Nikolaus Why not? 355 would become 600 normally. But It isn't possible to round of 300.

Comment: @Stranger Then how many digits, you want to have rounded in case of <100 ? Or in case of > 100000? Is there Andy rule?

Comment: @Nikolaus Check the latest answer. Problem-solved. Thanks for the help. However, I am leaving the values that are in hundreds for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could work with the logarithm of ten and adjust the digits.

```js
const
    format = n => v => {
        if (!v) return 0;
        const l = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(v))) - n + 1;

        return Math.round(v / 10 ** l) * 10 ** l;
    };

console.log([0, -9876, 320232, 2301, 12020305, 123456789].map(format(3)));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh yes you are correct.

Comment: @Stranger, please see edit.

Comment: Thank you, now It works exactly like how I want it to be. Just tested some other values.

Comment: Special care is needed for 0 and for negative values (use `Math.abs`)

Comment: @trincot, right there is not log of zero.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to first calculate how many numbers need to be rounded away, and then use that in a round.

`Math.round(1234/100)*100` would round to `1200` so we can use this to round. We then only need to determan what to replace 100 with in this example.

That is that would be a 1 followed by `LENGTH - 3` zeros. That number can be calculated as it is 10 to the power of `LENGTH - 3`, in JS: `10 ** (length - 3)`.

```js
var x = 320232;
var y = 2301;
var z = 12020305;

function my_round(number){
  var org_number = number;
  
  // calculate integer number
  var count = 0;
  if (number >= 1) ++count;

  while (number / 10 >= 1) {
    number /= 10;
    ++count;
  }
  
  // length - 3
  count = Math.round(count) - 3;
  if (count < 0){
    count = 0;
  }
  
  // 10 to the power of (length - 3)
  var helper = 10 ** count;
  
  return Math.round(org_number/helper)*helper;
}

alert(my_round(x));
alert(my_round(y));
alert(my_round(z));
```

It is not the prettiest code, though I tried to make it explainable code.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function roundToNthPlace(input, n) {
    let powerOfTen = 10 ** n
    return Math.round(input/powerOfTen) * powerOfTen;
}

console.log([320232, 2301,12020305, 423841].map(input => roundToNthPlace(input, 3)));

Output: [320000, 2000, 12020000, 424000]
```